# Scroll to hash and add spacing pure javaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using this pure JavaScript function to scroll to but want to add spacing to top, similar to what jquery - [...].offset().top - 160; - does. Any ideas? Much appreciated:

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
};
```

Comment: Only javascript, or is CSS also okay? It is easy to do with scroll-margin-top.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the whole page (Assign to `location.hash` does that), you can use the built-in [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) function...
Ho! by the way, you were overwriting it. ;)

```js
function scrollMeTo(hash) {
  let hashEl = document.querySelector("#" + hash);
  if (hashEl) {
    let hashPos = parseInt(hashEl.getBoundingClientRect().top) - 160;
    window.scrollTo(0, hashPos);
  }
}

scrollMeTo("two");
```

```css
.spacer{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>
<a id="one">ONE</a>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<a id="two">TWO</a>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<a id="three">THREE</a>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using that function on a click event from a link to anchor to a heading o a page. So idea is: click on a <a href="#page.htm#myTargetElement" > go to my page.htm and scroll to <h2 id="myTargetElement">